# CSS aligning search box

Tags: html, css

I've tried a few things but haven't been able to get the result I am after.

This is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2JTfc/4/embedded/result/

This is the code:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="test.jpg" />
    <form id="search_form">
        <input class="kw" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword" type="text"></input>
        <input id="loc" placeholder="Location" type="text"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button" id="search">
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Post</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I move the form so that it sits to the right of the test.jpg image in the header on the same line? Should I be surrounding it in divs and floating it, or is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#header img {vertical-align: middle;}

#header form {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
```

The last act is to remove `float: left` from the inputs.

Comment: This looks perfect, thank you. Can you see why my submit button now doesn't sit at the right height though?! http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2JTfc/7/embedded/result/

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that bit. It's a bit tricky, but this aligned it in my browser (Chrome): `#header input.button {vertical-align: middle; height: 27px; margin-top: -3px;}`

Answer (score 2):

Add `display:inline-block` to form

```
#search_form{
    display:inline-block
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2JTfc/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

The default `display` style of a form is `block`. So you'll need to change that to `inline-block` as you want it to appear inline. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6X7YM/)

```
#search_form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```